# How to apply function with multiple conditions on multiple columns to get new conditional columns in R

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns, mapply

Hello all a R noob here,

I hope you guys can help me with the following.

I need to transform multiple columns in my dataset to new columns based on the values in the original columns multiple times. This means that for the first transformation I use column 1, 2, 3 and if certain conditions are met the output results a new column with a 1 or a 0, for the second transformation I use columns 4, 5, 6 and the output should be a 1 or a 0 also. I have to do this 18 times. I already wrote a function which succesfully does the transformation if I impute the variables manually, but I would like to apply this function to all the desired columns at once. My desired output would be 18 new columns with 0's and 1's. Finally I will make a last column which will display a 1 if any of the 18 columns is a 1 and a 0 otherwise.

```
    df <- data.frame(admiss1 = sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                     admiss2 = sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                     admiss3 = sample(seq(as.Date('1990/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                     visit1 = sample(seq(as.Date('1995/01/01'), as.Date('1996/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                     visit2 = sample(seq(as.Date('1997/01/01'), as.Date('1998/01/01'), by="day"), 12),
                     reason1 = sample(3,12, replace = T),
                     reason2 = sample(3,12, replace = T),
                     reason3 = sample(3,12, replace = T))
    
    df$discharge1 <- df$admiss1 + 10
    df$discharge2 <- df$admiss2 + 10
    df$discharge3 <- df$admiss3 + 10
#every discharge date is 10 days after the admission date for the sake of this example
    
#now I have the following dataframe
#for the sake of it I included only 3 dates and reasons(instead of 18)
          admiss1    admiss2    admiss3     visit1     visit2 reason1 reason2 reason3 discharge1 discharge2 discharge3
    1  1990-03-12 1992-04-04 1998-07-31 1995-01-24 1997-10-07       2       1       3 1990-03-22 1992-04-14 1998-08-10
    2  1999-05-18 1990-11-25 1995-10-04 1995-03-06 1997-03-13       1       2       1 1999-05-28 1990-12-05 1995-10-14
    3  1993-07-16 1998-06-10 1991-07-05 1995-11-06 1997-11-15       1       1       2 1993-07-26 1998-06-20 1991-07-15
    4  1991-07-05 1992-06-17 1995-10-12 1995-05-14 1997-05-02       2       1       3 1991-07-15 1992-06-27 1995-10-22
    5  1995-08-16 1999-03-08 1992-04-03 1995-02-20 1997-01-03       1       3       3 1995-08-26 1999-03-18 1992-04-13
    6  1999-10-07 1991-12-26 1995-05-05 1995-10-24 1997-10-15       3       1       1 1999-10-17 1992-01-05 1995-05-15
    7  1998-03-18 1992-04-18 1993-12-31 1995-11-14 1997-06-14       3       2       2 1998-03-28 1992-04-28 1994-01-10
    8  1992-08-04 1991-09-16 1992-04-23 1995-05-29 1997-10-11       1       2       3 1992-08-14 1991-09-26 1992-05-03
    9  1997-02-20 1990-02-12 1998-03-08 1995-10-09 1997-12-29       1       1       3 1997-03-02 1990-02-22 1998-03-18
    10 1992-09-16 1997-06-16 1997-07-18 1995-12-11 1997-01-12       1       2       2 1992-09-26 1997-06-26 1997-07-28
    11 1991-01-25 1998-04-07 1999-07-02 1995-12-27 1997-05-28       3       2       1 1991-02-04 1998-04-17 1999-07-12
    12 1996-02-25 1993-03-30 1997-06-25 1995-09-07 1997-10-18       1       3       2 1996-03-06 1993-04-09 1997-07-05
    
    admissdate <- function(admis, dis, rsn, vis1, vis2){
      xnew <- ifelse(df[eval(substitute(admis))] >= df[eval(substitute(vis1))] & df[eval(substitute(dis))] <= df[eval(substitute(vis2))] & df[eval(substitute(rsn))] == 2, 1, 0)
      xnew <- ifelse(df[eval(substitute(admis))] >= df[eval(substitute(vis1))] & df[eval(substitute(admis))] <= df[eval(substitute(vis2))] & df[eval(substitute(dis))] >= df[eval(substitute(vis2))] & df[eval(substitute(rsn))] == 2, 1, xnew)
      return(xnew)
    }
```

I wrote this function to generate a 1 if the conditions are true and a 0 if the conditions are false.

-Condition 1: admission date and discharge date are between visit 1 and visit 2 + admission reason is 2.

-Condition 2: admission date is after visit 1 but before visit 2 and the discharge date is after visit 2 with also admission reason 2.

It should return 1 if these conditions are true and 0 if these conditions are false. Eventually, I will end up with 18 new variables with 1's or 0's and will combine them to make one variable with Admission between visit 1 and visit 2 (with reason 2).

If I manually impute the variable names it will work, but I cant make it work for all the variables at once. I tried to make a string vector with all the admiss dates, discharge dates and reasons and tried to transform them with mapply, but this does not work.

```
    admiss <- paste0(rep("admiss", 3), 1:3)
    discharge <- paste0(rep("discharge", 3), 1:3)
    reason <- paste0(rep("reason", 3), 1:3)
    visit1 <- rep("visit1",3)
    visit2 <- rep("visit2",3)
    
    mapply(admissdate, admis = admiss, dis = discharge, rsn = reason, vis1 = visit1, vis2 = visit2)
```

I have also considered lapply but here you have to define an X = ..., which I think I cannot use because I have multiple column that I want to impute, please correct me if I am wrong!

Also I considered using a for loop, but I don't know how to use that with multiple conditions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `If I manually impute the variable names it will work`. Can you show how do you manually impute the variables ? Also what would be your expected output for this example? 3 new columns + 1 other column with 1's and 0's ?

Comment: So if i a manually input the following: 'code' df$admis1 <- admissdate(admis = "admiss1", dis = "discharge1", vis1 = "visit1", rsn = "reason1", vis2 = "visit2")'code', I get a new variable with a 1 if the conditions are satisfied and a 0 if they are not. I will do the same for admiss1, discharge2 and reason 2 and will get a new column, etc. etc. In the end I have 18 new columns and then I have to combine them that any 1 in any of those columns will generate a 1 in the final column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the function to accept values instead of column names.

```
admissdate <- function(admis, dis, rsn, vis1, vis2){
  xnew <- as.integer(admis >= vis1 & dis <= vis2 & rsn == 2)
  xnew <- ifelse(admis >= vis1 & admis <= vis2 & dis >= vis2 & rsn == 2, 1, xnew)
  return(xnew)
}
```

Now create new columns -

```
admiss <- paste0("admiss", 1:3)
discharge <- paste0("discharge", 1:3)
reason <- paste0("reason", 1:3)
new_col <- paste0('newcol', 1:3)

df[new_col] <- Map(function(x, y, z) admissdate(x, y, z, df$visit1, df$visit2), 
                   df[admiss],df[discharge],df[reason])
#Additional column will be 1 if any of the value in the new column is 1.
df$result <- as.integer(rowSums(df[new_col]) > 0)
df
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Many, many thanks. So what is the function of Map in this context, is that a way of applying a function to multiple columns?

Comment: `Map` as same as `mapply`. Only difference is `Map` always returns a list whereas `mapply` may or may not return list. `Map` infact is a wrapper around `mapply`.